# VirtualProtectEx fails with ERROR_NOACCESS (error code 998)

Tags: c, winapi

```
CreateProcess("something.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 
    NULL, NULL, &sInfo, &pInfo);

ReadProcessMemory(pInfo.hProcess, (LPCVOID) (contx.Ebx + 8),
  (LPVOID) &baseAddress, sizeof(baseAddress), NULL);

hProcess=OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_VM_WRITE|PROCESS_VM_OPERATION,
  FALSE, pInfo.dwProcessId);

VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID) baseAddress, sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER),
    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, NULL);

WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID) baseAddress, (LPCVOID) pidh,
    sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER), NULL);
```

Why VirtualProctecEx gives me ERROR_NOACCESS ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [VirtualProtectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs say

> lpflOldProtect [out] A pointer to a variable that receives the
>   previous access protection of the first page in the specified region
>   of pages. If this parameter is NULL or does not point to a valid
>   variable, the function fails.

about the last argument.  You're passing NULL so should expect it to fail.

Its possible there are also other problems.  e.g. you don't check the return value from [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so `baseAddress` may be invalid.